# Mockito when starts actual method call Android UI Testing

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, android-testing

We have a `Configuration` class and `LocalStorage` class Configuration takes LocalStorage instance in constructor, LocalStorage takes `Context` in constructor. We are just trying to start with UI testing.
We are trying to do this

```
   private val localStorage = Mockito.mock(LocalStorage::class.java)

   // in our setup method
   Mockito.`when`(localStorage.getString(anyString())).thenReturn(str)
```

Here problem is that `getString()` method call starts happening immediately when tests are run. We have not even written actual test yet.

Mockito Android version: 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think what problem is may be in Mock final Kotlin classes during UI tests. It is looks like what you use plugin for Mockito to "open" classes.

Possible solutions:

1. Make LocalStorage to be interface, not class. (5th principle of SOLID, abstraction/realisation). Your problem may disappear because interfaces are open by their nature.
2. Use Mockk library to mock your LocalStorage and other classes. This framework is better for Kotlin.

Comment: Said classes are `open`, I can try `MockK` but for now I am looking for solution with Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using alternative approach?

`doReturn(str).`when`(localStorage).getString(anyString())`

(import needed: import org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn)

Comment: yes, this doesn't work either. We actually had found the real issue here. I will post that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was this `LocalStorage` was being initialized by our Application class. `Mock` fails when a dependency is already initialized before. Solution is to create a `TestApplication` with `CustomAndroidJUnitRunner`. Make sure dependencies are not pre-initialised and only initialise dependencies as per respective test's requirenment.